# PHP Form Intergration - Basket Format is Invalid

Tags: php, forms, opayo

Okay this is bugging me and I need a little help or a second pair of eyes.
I receive the following error message when testing and submitting my order confirmation form to sagepay for payment protocol 3.00:

> Status: INVALID
>
> Status Detail: 3021 : The Basket Format is invalid.

Here is the form content before encryption:

```html
VendorTxCode=wilkies-PAYMENT-20150414141140-263293450
&Amount=245.72
&Currency=GBP
&Description= from J&D Wilkie Ltd
&CustomerName=Foo-Wing Li
&CustomerEMail=foo@jdwilkie.co.uk
&VendorEMail=foo@jdwilkie.co.uk
&SendEMail=1
&eMailMessage=Thank you so very much for your order.
&BillingSurname=Li
&BillingFirstnames=Foo-Wing
&BillingAddress1=Marywell Works
&BillingAddress2=Marywell Brae
&BillingCity=Kirriemuir
&BillingPostCode=DD8 4BJ
&BillingCountry=GB
&BillingPhone=+4401575572502
&ApplyAVSCV2=0
&Apply3DSecure=0
&AllowGiftAid=0
&BillingAgreement=1
&BillingState=
&customerEmail=foo@jdwilkie.co.uk
&DeliveryFirstnames=Foo-Wing
&DeliverySurname=Li
&DeliveryAddress1=Marywell Works
&DeliveryAddress2=Marywell Brae
&DeliveryCity=Kirriemuir
&DeliveryPostCode=DD8 4BJ
&DeliveryCountry=GB
&DeliveryPhone=+4401575572502
&BasketXML=<basket>
<item>
<description>Oil Absorbency 80x86cm</description>
<productSku></productSku>
<productCode></productCode>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<unitNetAmount>102.68</unitNetAmount>
<unitTaxAmount>20.54</unitTaxAmount>
<unitGrossAmount>123.22</unitGrossAmount>
<totalGrossAmount>123.22</totalGrossAmount>
</item>
<item>
<description>Removal Blankets - 60x108</description>
<productSku></productSku>
<productCode></productCode>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<unitNetAmount>102.08</unitNetAmount>
<unitTaxAmount>20.42</unitTaxAmount>
<unitGrossAmount>122.50</unitGrossAmount>
<totalGrossAmount>122.50</totalGrossAmount>
</item>
<deliveryNetAmount></deliveryNetAmount>
<deliveryTaxAmount></deliveryTaxAmount>
<deliveryGrossAmount></deliveryGrossAmount>
</basket>
&SuccessURL=http://www.jdwilkie.co.uk/shop/cart/order_successful.php
&FailureURL=http://www.jdwilkie.co.uk/shop/cart/order_failed.php
```

Thanks

Comment: I've never used sagepay, but according to the docs: http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/36/protocol-3-00-basket-xml, productSku and productCode are not valid tags for the item XML

Comment: I have just tried removing the productSku and productCode but it still doesn't work. The PDF documentation I have http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/14206/download-document/FORM_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_050115.pdf?token=jwimtbXQc-MmWWdGJHNJZFeshXg2re_chVFqiebQ2wc says it is not require but can be included.

The demo uses the productSku and productCode so I assume it is okay to use them.

Comment: Only other thing I see is that &Amount line doesn't add up. The items add up to £225.18

Comment: Thanks Robert for noticing the error with the &Amount small mistake with the tax(VAT) calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have found a work around to my problem which has allowed me to narrow down where the problem lies.

All I have done is for the crypt form is removed the BasketXML data as this is not required by Sagepay or us.

```html
VendorTxCode=wilkies-PAYMENT-20150415105304-104385424
&Amount=255.73
&Currency=GBP
&Description=from J&D Wilkie Ltd
&CustomerName=Foo-Wing Li
&CustomerEMail=foo@jdwilkie.co.uk
&VendorEMail=foo@jdwilkie.co.uk
&SendEMail=1
&eMailMessage=Thank you so very much for your order.
&BillingSurname=Li
&BillingFirstnames=Foo-Wing
&BillingAddress1=Marywell Works
&BillingAddress2=Marywell Brae
&BillingCity=Kirriemuir
&BillingPostCode=DD8 4BJ
&BillingCountry=GB
&BillingPhone=+4401575572502
&ApplyAVSCV2=0
&Apply3DSecure=0
&AllowGiftAid=0
&BillingAgreement=1
&BillingState=
&customerEmail=foo@jdwilkie.co.uk
&DeliveryFirstnames=Foo-Wing
&DeliverySurname=Li
&DeliveryAddress1=Marywell Works
&DeliveryAddress2=Marywell Brae
&DeliveryCity=Kirriemuir
&DeliveryPostCode=DD8 4BJ
&DeliveryCountry=GB
&DeliveryPhone=+4401575572502
&BasketXML=
&SuccessURL=http://www.jdwilkie.co.uk/shop/cart/order_successful.php
&FailureURL=http://www.jdwilkie.co.uk/shop/cart/order_failed.php
```

There seems to be an error with the line VAT for each item and Gross Totals because they do not match the &Amount which is calculated from the total value of all items without VAT(Tax) then the VAT is calculated from the total of all items which gives a different result from the calculating line item VAT(Tax) then adding them together. If you work with VAT then you will understand what I mean. (hard to explain without making some kind of visual aid showing values and VAT(Tax)).